# Advantages and disadvantages of BLOBS (security)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, blob

A year ago, when I did simple PHP sites for people with a simple MySQL database, I was brought up to think that storing an entire image in the database was possible but a terrible idea. Instead you should store the image in the filesystem and simply store an image path in the database. I did agree with that from the start, despite my inexperience. It must keep the database light when you're backing it up to an external service, and makes it faster during actual local use. This later point, however, is complete speculation, and I'd like someone to clarify my theories:

When you store the images associated with objects in the database as a BLOB, when you request this object, is the whole object and its attributes (including this huge amount of image information) written to memory, even when it's not needed? E.g.

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > Object.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "blob"] 
2.0.0p247 :001 > Object.first.blob 
 => # not sure what this will return! I'm guessing a matrix-like wall of image information?
2.0.0p247 :003 > Object.first.name
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "Kitty"
```

I understand that the call to `Object.first.blob` will take a relatively long amount of time because we're retrieving a large amount of image information. But will `Object.first.name` take the same amount of time because `Object.first` writes everything, `id`, `name` and `blob` all to memory? **If the answer to this question is yes, that's a pretty good reason to never use BLOBS. However, if the answer is no, and rails is smart enough to only write requested attributes to memory then BLOBS suddenly become very attractive.**

To be quite honest with you guys I'm really crossing my fingers that you'll say storing images in a BLOB is fine and dandy. It'll make things so much easier. Backing up will be simple. It'll feel very nice to back up the dynamic content of the site in one 'modular' upload instead of resorting to some elaborate [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) augmented rake task to make sure the paths and their respective images are uploaded to an external location.

More so **it is absolutely impossible to make certain images private with Rails**. I've searched high, I've searched low, I've asked here on SO. Got a few upvotes, but no solid response. No tutorials online. Nothing. Bags of tutorials on how to store images in the assets folder, but nothing to make images private.

Let's say I have three types of user, `typeA`, `typeB` and `typeC`. And let's say I have three types of images. So database schema would be as follows:

*images*

```
=> ["image_path","blob","type"]
```

*users*

```
=> ["name","type"]
```

**What I want is that the users can request only the following:**

*typeA*:

> ***Can** only view images with a type of A*
>
> ***Cannot** view images with a type of B*
>
> ***Cannot** only view images with a type of C*

*typeB*:

> ***Can** only view images with a type of B*
>
> ***Cannot** view images with a type of A*
>
> ***Cannot** only view images with a type of C*

*typeC*:

> ***Can** only view images with a type of C*
>
> ***Cannot** view images with a type of A*
>
> ***Cannot** only view images with a type of B*

And yes, I could have given you the example with two types of user and image, but I really want to make sure you understand the problem; the actual system I have in mind will have hundreds of `types`.

Like I say, pretty simple idea, but I've found it impossible with rails, because all images are stored in the public folder! So a `typeB` user can just type `/assets/typeAImage.jpg` and they've got it! Heck, even someone who isn't a user can do it.

The `send_file` method won't work for me, because I'm not sending them the image as download per sae, I'm showing them image in the view.*

Now, using BLOBS would very neatly solve this problem if the images were stored in the database. I'm not sure of the actual syntax, but I could do something like this in a user view:

```
<% if current_user.type == image.type do %>
   <%= image_tag image.blob #=> <img src="/assets/typaAImage.jpg" alt="..." class="...">  %>
<% end %>
```

And yeah, you could do exactly the same thing with a path:

```
<% if current_user.type == image.type do %>
   <%= image_tag image.path #=> <img src="/assets/typaAImage.jpg" alt="..." class="..."> %>
<% end %>
```

but like I say, someone who isn't even a user could simply request `/assets/typeAImage.jpg`. **Impossible to do this if it's stored in a BLOB.**

**In conclusion:**

1. What's the problem with <strike>popplers</strike> BLOBS? I'm running a **postgres database on Heroku** with dozens of users per second. So yeah, not [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/), but not [Allegory on the Pointless of Life](http://www.leastpopularwebsites.com/leastthree.htm) either, so **performance matters**. They've also got a strong mobile following so speed is of the essence. Will using BLOBS clash with this?
2. How do I display an image stored in a BLOB in a view?
3. And just to confirm, BLOBS will allow me to securely show secure secret images to certain members over https?
4. What about database backup speed? That'll take a hit, but I want to backup the images anyway and it's a nightly thing so who cares if it's slow? Right?
5. The images will be secure so long as the backup is encrypted, right? And just as passwords are stored as hashes within the database, should I store my super-secret BLOBS in an encrypted format as well? I'm thinking yes... Do you reckon [bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) will be up to the task? I don't see why not.
6. Are BLOBS considered amateurish and lazy?

**...and finally a bonus point (possibly outside the scope of the question):**

*= As I wrote this I was thinking 'yes, but showing the image in the view *is* downloading the image to them. So can the `send_file` method be used to create private images in the way I describe and use the filesystem to store the images?

Comment: It sounds like you're more concerned about Rails limitations regarding `bytea` fields (assuming that's what you mean by "blob") than about anything to do with the database its self.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: Yes, it's possible in rails to lazy load some attributes, but by default Active Record does not support it  [There is a gem for this though](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/lazy_columns). (DataMapper does support this by default, and there is a [plugin for Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/LazyAttributes.html) as well).

For the second part: the biggest drawback of your approach is performance. Assets are best served via a fast, static web server that can load the files from the filesystem, and not through a dynamic application. Clogging up the database server to query large blobs is not recommended, especially since it's much harder to scale a database than a file system.

And for the last part: there are various options you can use to hide files from the user, and only serve them when needed. One of the options is [X-SendFile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), or [X-Accel-Redir](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) where you can specify a filename inside the returned headers in Rails, and the web-server that is proxying the requests (and which also support this header) will pick that up, and serve that file. This is not a redirect, so the URL will still be the same, and the file can still be hidden from normal access. Of course for this you have to proxy your requests to rails through a web-server, which is usually already happening at least at the load-balancing level, or if you are using passenger.

Also note that you can [tell Rails to send X-SendFile headers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#x-sendfile-headers) when serving the ordinary asset files as well.

[Also see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430463/120917)

Comment: I'm using Heroku, can I do all of this?